# Java etcd API (etcd) client does not detect when etcd is not running

Tags: etcd

I am using jetcd, a great Java client for etcd, and am trying to connect to etcd.  It works fine when etcd is running (ie. a client is established and I can do put/get calls), but I still get a client even when etcd is not running.

My question: how can I detect (when I get build my client) that etcd is not running (which I can then log something or wait/reconnect)?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
import io.etcd.jetcd.Client;
:
:
connections = {"http://etcd-1:2379", "http://etcd-2:2379", "http://etcd3:2379"}
Client client = Client.builder().endpoints(connections).build();
log.debug("client: {}", client);
```

The problem is I get a valid client returned, but no exception, even when none of the etcd nodes is running.  I would have though I would get a 'null" returned or an exception would be thrown.

Is there a better solution, or am I doing something incorrectly?

As an interim solution I can probably try a "put" or "get" call which would presumably cause an error/exception/wait but this does not seem to be the right approach.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Etcd (and indeed any network service) is inherently unreliable, so your program must be able to deal with failures at any time: not just upon startup. You can make your program "test" the connection, but you might as well not, because a test is no guarantee of what will happen next.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but it does not answer the question.  To be specific, I want to know if ETCD is running *when I try to build the client* - Since the client return is valid, I will get errors when I do get/put calls (again, I can accommodate this but I am asking if there is a way to detect etcd is not running when I build the client)

Comment: @EricBroda did you figure it out? It seems to just hang indefinitely if ETCD is not reachable.

Comment: I ended up switching to the Python ETCD client.  But I think this is the intended behaviour.  My understanding is that interaction with ETCD is expected to be "stateless".  This means that the identification of the absence of ETCD will only occur when a message is sent.

So, when you acquire the ETCD client, what you are really doing is just establishing the configuration that will let you interact with ETCD.